# Angular 6 file upload

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a REST API that upload images to s3 and returns the response. The API works perfectly using Postman.

The problem arrises when calling the API from frontend. I am using Angular 6.

I am getting `Error: Unsupported content type: application/json` error. Although I am setting the headers properly.

Here is my `Angular 6` code.

```
export class UploadComponent {
  percentDone: number;
  uploadSuccess: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  upload(file: File) {
    this.singleBasicUpload(file);
  }

  singleBasicUpload(file: File) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    });
    const options = { headers: headers };
    this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/upload`, file, options).subscribe(response => {
      console.log('response', response);
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my `S3` code in backend Node.js

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: constants.IAM_USER_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: constants.IAM_USER_SECRET,
});

const BUCKET_NAME = constants.BUCKET_NAME;
const ACL = 'public-read';
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

export async function S3Upload(req, res) {
  const chunks = [];

  let fname;
  let fileType;
  let fileEncodingType;

  const busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers,
  });

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    fname = filename.replace(/ /g, '_');
    fileType = mimetype;
    fileEncodingType = encoding;

    file.on('data', data => {
      // you will get chunks here will pull all chunk to an array and later concat it.
      console.log(chunks.length);
      chunks.push(data);
    });
    file.on('end', () => {
      console.log(`File [${filename}] Finished`);
    });
  });
  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    const userId = UUID();
    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, // your s3 bucket name
      Key: `${userId}-${fname}`,
      Body: Buffer.concat(chunks), // concatinating all chunks
      ACL,
      ContentEncoding: fileEncodingType, // optional
      ContentType: fileType, // required
    };
    // we are sending buffer data to s3.
    S3.upload(params, (err, s3res) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({
          err,
          status: 'error',
        });
      } else {
        return res.send({
          data: s3res,
          message: 'Image successfully uploaded.',
        });
      }
    });
  });
  req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

[Network description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpXfl.png)

Comment: You're not adding the `options` variable to your POST request. You've created the variable, you're just not using it

Comment: Sorry that is just a typo! I actually have in my code. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question with the actual code please? I'll take a look

Comment: Just updated it, thanks!

Comment: If you check in the developer tools (F12) network panel, can you see what the value of the `Content-Type` header is being set to in the request headers? Your error message suggests `application/json`, but I can't reproduce that issue

Comment: It is set to `application/json`. i added a screenshot to the actual post

Comment: If i use that code in StackBlitz, it sends its as `multipart/form-data` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwdumw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts If possible, can you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? You can use a fake URL if you prefer

Comment: I added the code to the above stackblitz. The project i am working on, it is a new project. It just has the upload component on it. It works with Postman though

Comment: Can you save it and share the URL of the StackBlitz then please?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought I did. Here it is https://angular-tm1hhy.stackblitz.io

Comment: That;s still not using the `application/json` content-type, it's sending `mutlipart/form-data`... Admittedly, it's sending the wrong data but still... I've updated the original StackBlitz. Can you try that, and see if you're still getting the same error? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwdumw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Nope, no luck. Still same error

Comment: Sorry then, without being able to reproduce the issue that's not much I can do to help

Comment: No worries man! thanks for the help